# Do I need to control database version for updates?

Tags: android, database, version, upgrade

I am about to release an Android app and I am a little bit concerned about the database versioning.

The thing is I only use the database during execution time, everytime I start the application I remove all the contents because they don´t need to be persistant. The code is like this:

```
public synchronized void createDatabase() {
    if (database == null) {
        database =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASENAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }

    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Xxxxxxxx.TABLE_NAME);
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Yyyyyyyy.TABLE_NAME);
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Oooooooo.TABLE_NAME);
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Ppppppppp.TABLE_NAME);
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Mmmmmmmmm.TABLE_NAME);
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Aaaaaaaaa.TABLE_NAME);

    database.execSQL(Xxxxxxxx.CREATE_PROVIDERS_TABLE);
    database.execSQL(Yyyyyyyy.CREATE_CONTENTS_TABLE);
    database.execSQL(Oooooooo.CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
    database.execSQL(Ppppppppp.CREATE_EVENTS_ANSWERS_TABLE);
    database.execSQL(Mmmmmmmmm.CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
    database.execSQL(Aaaaaaaaa.CREATE_SUBCATEGORY_TABLE);
}
```

My question is, considering how I remove everything when I start the app, do I need to control different versions? What if in the future I add a new column? Will it work propperly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to worry at all about db versioning.

If you actually change the DB schema in a future version it doesn't matter since all the tables will be dropped/recreated at next launch.

Answer (score 0):

***considering how I remove everything when I start the app, do I need to control different versions? What if in the future I add a new column? Will it work propperly?***

you are dropping all the tables and recreating them so you did not need to control the version of your database, you have to change the version of database if you upgrade the existing database and modify the tables. hope this will help